# Alt + Tab How to open only windows from active monitor

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, windows-11

I have windows 11 and two monitors. When I press Alt + Tab window switchers shows only on the main monitor and it shows all the opened windows on the system.

Is there a way to open window switcher only on the active monitor and make it shows only applications from that monitor?

By active monitor I mean the monitor on which I clicked last.

Answer (score 1):

Try using  <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

If that doesn't help, you will need an Alt-Tab replacement.
One that I know of is
[DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/).
Unfortunately the Alt-Tab options are in the commercial version,
starting at $34, but with a trial period of 30 days.

Comment: Yeah I know about Win + Tab but it doesn't feel the same. I can't change windows as snappy as using Alt+Tab. I think I'll pass on paid option too. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Win +Tab is useful to see, but doesn't cycle. I gave a thumbs up still. I'm gonna copy paste this from another comment of mine: "It blows me away MICROSOFT this nonsense is still the case on Windows 10 in 2023! I might have 4 screens, 1 playing video, 2 running my dev tests, 3 for miscellaneous stuff and 4 the MAIN one for my work! So when I cycle, take a guess Microsoft: which programs do I really want to cycle? Can you guess it? Or maybe spend $10m on a focus group to find out? But please fix this nonsense!"

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using Windows PowerToys (free).

First use PowerToys FancyZones and create a layout that covers the entire screen, do this by creating a grid zone and then click and drag the first zone to merge them all into one. You can also disable "Space around zone" and "round corners" in settings. Select layout on both monitors. Place windows in zone by dragging them while holding shift.

Then use PowerToys Keyboard Manager to map <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>Page up</kbd> (this is the shortcut of FancyZones to switch window in zone.)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify upon what "harrymc" said:
In remapping keys using this method be sure to Click on "Remap a shortcut" not Remap a key" If you try to do "remap a key" then it will only let you choose "Alt" OR "Tab" but not both.

Alternatively, if remapping keys with powertoys isnt for you then I recommend using fancy zones to do exactly what harrymc said, and then you can remap keys using AHK (v1 or v2).

In V2 writing a simpleAHK script to change your hotkey would look like this:

```
Requires AutoHotkey v2
SingleInstance Force
InstallKeyboardHook()
Persistent()

!Tab::#PgDn
```

Now, I will say, implementing the fancy zones suggestions from HarryMC is a bit trickier and I myself am having some issues getting that working. Harry, if you would please post a more specific guide (maybe with some screenshots) it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would also like to add that Win + Tab (at least in win11 and probably win10 will show you the open windows on each monitor separately

Comment: Definitely does on 10, I was actually wondering if 11 does it, too.